# Emacs prefix justifications?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, history

Do any old-school emacs-ers know the justification for the prefix key's C-c and C-x? I'm binding my own keys for some custom functions, and I'm wondering if there's any sort of "standard" that defines consistency for these prefixes.

So far the only thing I've noticed is that C-x is used for manipulating buffers (C-x C-f, C-x C-s, etc), but I haven't found a general theme for C-c yet. Thoughts?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html), <kbd>C-c</kbd> followed by a single key is conventionally reserved for user-defined bindings, along with some other prefixes, which see.

I think people have a lot of strategies for managing their personal bindings, for example, I remap CapsLock to <kbd>F2</kbd> and root most of my personal keymaps from there.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer from Rorschach: From what I think I understand, `C-x <something>` is anything that interacts outside the current buffer (for example `C-x C-s` saves the buffer to a file — which is outside the buffer).